# Show images from TEXT section on PAGE wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to show all images on a Page in wordpress. My wordpress page is set up like you see in the image below.

[image]

What I want to do is show each of these images on a custom page I have made, called Portrait Album. See code below. I guess it is [the opposite of this that](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87909/how-to-retrieve-text-only-from-wp-content-not-from-wp-excerpt) i want to implement.

I am not sure how I can show each image in the `Text` section. Does anyone out there know how to do this? should be obvious but I cannot find an answer anywhere.

I know `get_content()` will show the content, but how can I specifically show the images, so I can show these in a loop enabling me to make a grid using css and create a photo gallery.

currently this is the code I have:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Portrait Album */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="portrait-page" style="background-color: black;">
     <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
     <?php the_content(); ?>
     echo "<img src='".wp_get_attachment_url( $the_post->ID )."' />";
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is something like this, where `col-1-3` is one-third of the width of the page

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1-3">
    echo "<img src='"RELEVANT PHP CODE HERE"' />"
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use some JS library for client side processing to album

Comment: @Justinas like which library? i don't think a library is necessary, just a couple of lines of php should do it, but unfortunately I don't know what these should be and cannot find anything online.

Comment: Just google for what you want (PHP is server side and Album will require user interactions - JS) https://plugins.jquery.com/jgallery/

Comment: @Justinas i am not worried about the front end, i know what to do once i can get the images into an array and loop through them.

Comment: So what you want? Add `break` before `endwhile` to show only one image

Comment: I want to show all images. is my question not clear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120402/discussion-between-justinas-and-phantom).